# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift when loading a WebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, runtime-error

I followed a tutorial to make a web view on an iOS app and I don't get any errors. However, when I build the app to test it on the Simulator, I get the error:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Webview : UIWebView!
    var URLpath = "http://google.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadAddressURL(){
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:URLpath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL:requestURL!)
        Webview.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

When I run the app the `Webview.loadRequest(request)` is marked in red and displays the error.
In the debugger I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Just check whether webview is connected properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are for sure made mistake in connection your `UIWebView` from storyboard/xib to code. You should remove existed connection in storyboard/xib, delete line

```
@IBOutlet var Webview : UIWebView!
```

and then connect it again. Proper declaration should contain word `weak` in order:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Webview : UIWebView!
```

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means that there was an assertion failure in your code.

Code looks ok. but looks like your UIWebView control is not linked correctly in storyboard. 
Try liking IBOutlet again to corresponding uiWebView in storyboard.
@IBOutlet var Webview : UIWebView!